# EWS Managed API : Reply to a message while adding an internet header

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server-2010, ews-managed-api

I am building a small client that can automatically reply to some emails. I would like to add a custom internet header to these replies.

What I tried to do is to set the extended property to the email I receive, and use the `EmailMessage.Reply` method.

But it does not work. I also tried to use the `EmailMessage.CreateReply`. However, it creates a `ResponseMessage` object that has no `SetExtendedProperty` method.

This the relevant part of the code :

```
private static readonly ExtendedPropertyDefinition _redFlag = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.InternetHeaders, "X-RED", MapiPropertyType.String);
private static readonly PropertySet _customHeaders = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, _redFlag);

/* ... some code to connect to Exchange Service ... */

EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, id, _customHeaders);
email.SetExtendedProperty(_redFlag, "test");
email.Reply(new MessageBody(answer), false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to save the [`ResponseMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.responsemessage_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) in the `Drafts` folder [via the `Save()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634401%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) and then you can obtain an instance of the [`EmailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). This is the [same pattern used to add attachments to message replies](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/18/Replying-with-attachments-to-an-email-message-with-EWS.aspx).

```cs
var message = (EmailMessage) Item.Bind(service, new ItemId(uniqueId), PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
var reply = message.CreateReply(false);
reply.BodyPrefix = "Response text goes here";
var replyMessage = reply.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts); // default is drafts folder - this is explicit
replyMessage.SetExtendedProperty(_redFlag, "test");
replyMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
replyMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: Hi @SliverNinja. Any idea why this does not work on Office 365 Group mailboxes?